# SQL syntax error when creating new table in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I wont to create sql tables but I receive error.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'CREATE TABLE `articles_ratings` ( `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `a' at line 10
```

```
CREATE TABLE `articles` (
   `ID` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `a_title` varchar( 255 ) ,
   `a_subtitle` tinytext,
   `a_content` text,
   PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )
) 

CREATE TABLE `articles_ratings` (
   `ID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   `article_id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
   `rating_value` tinyint( 2 ) NOT NULL ,
   `rater_ip` varchar( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
)
```

Comment: Looks like you have a stray comma at the end of `articles_ratings` and also forgot the `;` to terminate the first `CREATE TABLE` statement, which is why MySQL points to a syntax error at the start of the second `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @kazik1616 Ah yes, the elusive archaeology badge

Answer (score 1):

Add the primary key to your articles ratings statement or remove the last comma.

```
CREATE TABLE articles ( 
    ID int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    a_title varchar( 255 ) , 
    a_subtitle tinytext, 
    a_content text, 
  PRIMARY KEY ( ID ) 
);
CREATE TABLE articles_ratings ( 
    ID INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
  article_id int( 11 ) NOT NULL , 
  rating_value tinyint( 2 ) NOT NULL , 
  rater_ip varchar( 20 ) NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY ( ID ) 
);
```